# replace second field in a file from git log output

Tags: linux, bash, git, awk, sed

I have a file with full of file routes and timestamps.

```
xxxx/view/css/animate.css/3.1.1/animate.min.css: 1494509091
xxxx/view/fonts/cinzel/fonts.css: 1494509091
xxxx/view/fonts/garamondcondot-book/fonts.css: 1494509092
xxxx/view/fonts/gotham-narrow/fonts.css: 1494509092
xxxx/view/fonts/gotham/fonts.css: 1494509092
xxxx/view/fonts/greatvibes/fonts.css: 1494509092
xxxx/view/fonts/indie-flower/fonts.css: 1494509092
xxxx/view/fonts/katibeh/fonts.css: 1494509092
xxxx/view/fonts/lobster-two/fonts.css: 1494509092
xxxx/view/fonts/museo/fonts.css: 1494509092
xxxx/view/fonts/myriad-pro/fonts.css: 1494509092
```

These timestamps isn't right, so i need to check with git log the right last editied timestamp, with this command:

```
git log -1 --pretty="format:%ct" xxxx/view/css/animate.css/3.1.1/animate.min.css
```

The problem is that i have more than 500-600 files to check and replace the correct timestamp. I tried with awk, sed but is not good.
Here is my examples:

```
variables=$(git log -1 --pretty="format:%ct") 

     while read line ; do
         replacement="$variables $line"
         sed 's/,.*:/ $replacement/' <<< "$line"
     done < files.yml
```

another:

```
  file="files2.yml"
  files=$(cat files.yml | awk '{print $1}' | cut -d ':' -f 1)
  for i in $files;do
    new=$(git log -1 --pretty="format:%ct" $i)
    sed "s/    .*:/ $new/" files2.yml
  done
```

Have you any tips?

Comment: check if this works: `sed -E 's|(.*): .*|echo \1: $(git log -1 --pretty="format:%ct" \1)|e' files.yml`

Comment: I got this error:  fatal: invalid object name 'catalog/view/css/animate.css/3.1.1/animate.min.css'..   With every files.

Comment: I missed the `:` and modified the command, can you check again?

Comment: Waa, it works! Thank you very much!!! Have you any good resource to learn sed normally?

Comment: there are learning resources in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info ... I have a book on `GNU sed` too https://github.com/learnbyexample/learn_gnused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -E 's|(.*): .*|echo \x27\1\x27: $(git log -1 --pretty="format:%ct" "\1")|e' files.yml
```

- `(.*): .*` will capture text before last `:` and space in the line and match rest of the line as well
- `echo \x27\1\x27:` to put the file path back, `\1` will refer to text matched by `(.*)` and `\x27` is single quote character
- `$(git log -1 --pretty="format:%ct" "\1")` the command you want to execute
- `e` flag allows to execute the entire modified line as a shell command (not sure if this is specific to `GNU sed`, but the question is tagged `linux` so this should be okay)

Note that this is not a robust command. File name with spaces and other shell metacharacters may cause issues.